# ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(980)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, ssl

I am try to develop a flutter project using url_launcher plugin where i encounter with this issue

E/chromium(11062): [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(980)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202

The url i have used is "https://see.ntc.net.np/results/grade/"
I have also used other url and all are working great but can figure it this url is not workin